# Qué significa <vez> en la oración ¿Quién da la vez?

Tags: discusión

Qué significa  en la oración ¿Quién da la vez? Si  significa the time cómo puede significa  como alguien me dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta expresión, "**dar la vez**", se utiliza cuando se llega a un sitio y se ha de hacer una fila o cola esperando el turno que le corresponde, entonces normalmente se pregunta **¿ Quién da la vez?**, **¿ Quién es el último?** (¿ quién llegó el último?). En ese momento alguien dice, "**yo soy el último**", "**yo llegue el último**". Así el último que se encuentra en la fila de la cola esperando su turno, es el que "**da la vez**" a quien lo pregunta.

Para entender la expresión "**dar la vez**" lo importante es centrarse en la palabra "**vez**". En este contexto "**vez**" se asocia al elemento latino "**vicis**" que en origen significa "turno o variación".

Así pues "**dar la vez**", significa "**dar el lugar**", "**dar el puesto**", "**dar el turno**" que otra persona ocupaba hasta ese momento.

Cuando llegamos a una fila o larga cola, normalmente ya hay una persona que se ubica en el último puesto o posición (al final de la cola). Entonces el que llega de nuevo "**pide la vez**" preguntando, **¿ quién es el que ocupa el último puesto o lugar?**, de esta manera la persona que contesta y que ocupaba hasta ese momento el último puesto o lugar, "**da la vez al recién llegado**", sustituyendo al que era el último y ocupando su lugar, es decir, el "**lugar**" que corresponde al último de la fila o cola.

Si otra persona viniera e hiciera lo mismo, nosotros que somos los últimos de la cola, "**daremos la vez**", es decir, "**daremos o cederemos el lugar de último**" al nuevo que llega a la cola.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti !

Answer (score 1):

Según la RAE:
https://dle.rae.es/vez

...tenemos que:

> **Vez**: Tiempo u ocasión de hacer algo por turno u orden.

Ejemplo: *Le llegó la vez de entrar.*

Por tanto, la pregunta *¿Quién da la vez?* la emplea quien llega a un proceso o actividad basada en turnos ordenados, con intención de participar de la misma.

Y lo hace para identificar, y tomar como referencia en la sucesión de turnos, a la última persona que previamente se ha incorporado a ese orden (y que, por definición, es la única que puede dar esa *vez*).

Answer (score 0):

“¿Quién da la vez?” equivale a preguntar “¿quién es el último?” en lugares como un comercio, donde no es fácil hacer una cola.

“La vez” significa “el turno”. El último que entró es quien dice al que acaba de entrar cuándo es su turno.